Packing multiple projects into singular NuGet package
I would like to pack a Roslyn source generator and another project that contains the attributes the source generator acts upon together into one NuGet package. To do this, I've decided that using a third project collecting the other two would be the best option.
Here's what that third project file looks like:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>

    <IncludeBuildOutput>false</IncludeBuildOutput>
    <IsPackable>true</IsPackable>
    <NoWarn>$(NoWarn);NU5128</NoWarn>

    <PackageId>MyGenerators</PackageId>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="$(SrcPath)\MyProject.SourceGenerators\MyProject.SourceGenerators.csproj"
                      PrivateAssets="all" />
    <ProjectReference Include="$(SrcPath)\MyProject.SourceGenerators.Core\MyProject.SourceGenerators.Core.csproj"
                      PrivateAssets="all" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="$(OutputPath)\MyProject.SourceGenerators.dll"
          Pack="true" PackagePath="analyzers/dotnet/cs"
          Visible="false" />

    <None Include="$(OutputPath)\MyProject.SourceGenerators.Core.dll"
          Pack="true" PackagePath="lib/netstandard2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>

Using dotnet pack to create the package works as intended. However, when I locally consume MyGenerators, NuGet throws NU1101 twice:
Unable to find package MyProject.SourceGenerators.Core. No packages exist with this id in source(s): local, nuget.org
Unable to find package MyProject.SourceGenerators. No packages exist with this id in source(s): local, nuget.org

The local source points to the directory the above project's package is placed in. MyGenerators itself does, of course, get found. It's the project references that NuGet treats as packages themselves.
I've tried out some combinations of removing PrivateAssets, setting DevelopmentDependency to true, changing package paths and output types, but I can't get the final package to behave the way I need it to.
What could I be doing wrong here?

You probably just don't need the <ProjectReference> bits; if you're shipping generators or other Roslyn hooks, they just ship in the package directly - no project-ref or package-ref required; example: https://github.com/DapperLib/DapperAOT/blob/main/src/Dapper.AOT/Dapper.AOT.csproj - note if you do intend additional packages to the dragged in, you'll need to upload them accordingly

I appreciate the comment, but I do not wish to ship the packages separately. The generator is useless without the attributes in the .Core project.

In the example I give, Dapper.AOT, the Dapper.AOT package is the package/assembly that contains the attributes (and pretty much just the attributes) - dragging the analyzer bits along for the journey as part of installing that package. If you want a separate package to be installed, then you're going to need to ship that separate package.

I have to apologize for a lack of context given. In the third project file, I was setting Version to 0.0.1. This is what's causing the problem when consuming the package, even when specifically pulling in version 0.0.1. The problem no longer occurs after setting the Version of the package to 1.0.0 or above. I'm stumped as to why that's the culprit.
